# Lua: arbitrary number of return values

Tags: lua, variadic-functions

I am coming back to Lua after a long time of C++ only and I am currently trying to wrap my head around some of the more complicated things again.

imagine a small utility function, that looks like this, to call a function multiple times for an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
-- helper to call a function multiple times at once
function smartCall(func, ...)
    -- the variadic arguments
    local args = {...}
    -- the table to save the return values
    local ret = {}
    -- iterate over the arguments
    for i,v in ipairs(args) do
            -- if it is a table, we unpack the table
        if type(v) == "table" then
            ret[i] = func(unpack(v))
        else
            -- else we call the function directly
            ret[i] = func(v)
        end
    end
    -- return the individual return values
    return unpack(ret)
end
```

then I can do something like this:

```
local a,b,c = smartCall(math.abs, -1, 2.0, -3.0)
local d,e,f = smartCall(math.min, {1.0, 0.3}, {-1.0, 2.3}, {0.5, 0.7})
```

this works, but I am wondering if there is a more convinient way, since my version involves alot of unpack and temporary tables.

ty

Comment: Small warning: Your code assumes that `func`` returns a single value; if it returns more, those are ignored. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you write `smartCall` in C, it'll be simpler and you won't need to create tables. I don't know whether this is convenient for you, though.

Comment: hey, I am working on some pure lua modules and this is basically a try to avoid rewriting alot of duplicate code. but since its for some vector math i might just forget about this idea and rather write the duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

For a moment I thought about passing everything as strings then manipulating the string to make a valid function call and calling it using `tostring`; just then I realized it's not at all more efficient than unpacking here.

Then I thought about putting an extra argument which specifies the number of arguments of the function you want to smartly call. This way for functions with a fixed number of arguments `smartCall` can pass groups of its arguments to the function being called. Again, this one needs extracting table parts or arithmetic to find argument numbers.

So, I can't think of any simpler function. And `unpack` is efficient enough and it doesn't majorly affect the overall execution time of such calls.